# Preencher DropDownListFor dinamicamente com JQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando preencher um `DropDownListFor` dinamicamente. Este `DropDownListFor` eh para exibir as cidades do estado, por exemplo: O usuário escolhe o estado e neste `DropDown` é exibido as cidades desse estado. O problema, é que no model o `SelectListItem` das cidades está vazio e quando renderizo a página, e por isto está dando a seguinte **Exception:**

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'cidadeSelected'.
```

Como resolver isso ?

**Model**

```
    //estado
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> estados { get; set; }    
    public IEnumerable<long> estadoSelected { get; set; }
    //
    //cidade
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cidades             { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selecione a cidade")]
    public IEnumerable<long> cidadeSelected                { get; set; }
    //
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.estadoSelected)" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Estado </label>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.estadoSelected, Model.estados, "-Escolha o estado-", new { Class = "form-control", data_placeholder = "Selecione o estado" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.estadoSelected)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.cidadeSelected)" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Condado </label>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cidadeSelected, Model.cidades, new { Class = "form-control", data_placeholder = "Selecione a cidade" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cidadeSelected)
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido. Apenas criei uma lista vazia de cidades e adicionei ao Model e funcionou blzinha.

fiz assim.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult add(){
            AddTaxModel model = new AddTaxModel();
            model.estados = new SelectList(new EstadoDAO().findAll(), "id", "nome");
            model.cidades = new SelectList(new List<Cidade>(), "id", "nome");                      
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Model

```
public class CascadingDropDownSampleModel
    {

        public IDictionary<string, string> Makes { get; set; }
    }
```

> Controller

```
 public class CascadingDropDownSampleController : Controller
    {
        #region "Public Actions"


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> makes = GetSampleMakes();
            CascadingDropDownSampleModel viewModel = new CascadingDropDownSampleModel()
            {
                Makes = makes
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult GetSampleModels(string selectedMake)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> models = GetSampleModelsFromSelectedMake(selectedMake);
            return Json(models);
        }


        public ActionResult GetSampleColors(string selectedModel)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> colors = GetSampleColorsFromSelectedModel(selectedModel);
            return Json(colors);
        }

        #endregion

        #region "Private Methods"


        private IDictionary<string, string> GetSampleMakes()
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> makes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            makes.Add("1", "Acura");
            makes.Add("2", "Audi");
            makes.Add("3", "BMW");

            return makes;
        }

        private IDictionary<string, string> GetSampleModelsFromSelectedMake(string selectedMake)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> models = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            switch (selectedMake)
            {
                case "1":
                    models.Add("1", "Integra");
                    models.Add("2", "RL");
                    models.Add("3", "TL");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    models.Add("4", "A4");
                    models.Add("5", "S4");
                    models.Add("6", "A6");
                    break;
                case "3":
                    models.Add("7", "3 series");
                    models.Add("8", "5 series");
                    models.Add("9", "7 series");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();

            }

            return models;
        }


        private IDictionary<string, string> GetSampleColorsFromSelectedModel(string selectedModel)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> colors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            switch (selectedModel)
            {
                case "1":
                    colors.Add("1", "Green");
                    colors.Add("2", "Sea Green");
                    colors.Add("3", "Pale Green");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    colors.Add("4", "Red");
                    colors.Add("5", "Bright Red");
                    break;
                case "3":
                    colors.Add("6", "Teal");
                    colors.Add("7", "Dark Teal");
                    break;
                case "4":
                    colors.Add("8", "Azure");
                    colors.Add("9", "Light Azure");
                    colors.Add("10", "Dark Azure");
                    break;
                case "5":
                    colors.Add("11", "Silver");
                    colors.Add("12", "Metallic");
                    break;
                case "6":
                    colors.Add("13", "Cyan");
                    break;
                case "7":
                    colors.Add("14", "Blue");
                    colors.Add("15", "Sky Blue");
                    colors.Add("16", "Racing Blue");
                    break;
                case "8":
                    colors.Add("17", "Yellow");
                    colors.Add("18", "Red");
                    break;
                case "9":
                    colors.Add("17", "Brown");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();

            }

            return colors;
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

> View

```
@model CSDropdownListMVC4.Models.CascadingDropDownSampleModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CascadingDropDown Demonstration in ASP.NET MVC 4";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/CascadingDropDownSample.js"></script>
}


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Marca</td>
        <td>
            <select id="make" class="size-200">
                <option value="-1">Selecione uma marca</option>
                @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> make in Model.Makes)
                {
                    <option value="@make.Key">@make.Value</option>
                }
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Modelo</td>
        <td>
            <select id="model" class="size-200" disabled>
                <option value="-1">Selecione o modelo</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cor</td>
        <td>
            <select id="color" class="size-200" disabled>
                <option value="-1">Selecione a cor</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> Jquery

```
$(function () {
    var cascadingDropDownSample = new CascadingDropDownSample();

    $('#make').on('change', function () {
        var selectedMake = $(this).val();

        if (selectedMake !== "-1") {
            $.post('/CascadingDropDownSample/GetSampleModels',
                { selectedMake: selectedMake },
                function (data) {
                    cascadingDropDownSample.resetCascadingDropDowns();
                    cascadingDropDownSample.getSampleModelsSuccess(data);
                });
        }
        else {

            cascadingDropDownSample.resetCascadingDropDowns();
        }
    });

    $('#model').on('change', function () {
        var selectedModel = $(this).val();

        if (selectedModel !== "-1") {
            $.post('/CascadingDropDownSample/GetSampleColors',
                { selectedModel: selectedModel },
                function (data) {
                    cascadingDropDownSample.resetColors();
                    cascadingDropDownSample.getSampleColorsSuccess(data);
                });
        }
        else {
            cascadingDropDownSample.resetColors();
        }
    });
});

function CascadingDropDownSample() {
    this.resetCascadingDropDowns = function () {
        this.resetModels();
        this.resetColors();
    };

    this.getSampleModelsSuccess = function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, textValue) {
            $('#model').append($('<option />', { value: key, text: textValue }));
        });
        $('#model').attr('disabled', false);
    };

    this.getSampleColorsSuccess = function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, textValue) {
            $('#color').append($('<option />', { value: key, text: textValue }));
        });
        $('#color').attr('disabled', false);
    };

    this.resetModels = function () {
        $('#model option').remove();
        $('#model').append($('<option />', { value: '-1', text: 'Please select a model' }));
        $('#model').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    };

    this.resetColors = function () {
        $('#color option').remove();
        $('#color').append($('<option />', { value: '-1', text: 'Please select a color' }));
        $('#color').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    };
}
```

**Referência**
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-DropDownList-6ef6ffcb